# What is duration of tithi according to Hindu panchang?

Tags: astrology, calendar, panchang

What is duration of tithi according to Hindu panchang?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithi

Answer (score 2):

From Vedic Astrology: An Integrated Approach by P.V.R Narsimha Rao

> In lunar calendar, one day stands for one tithi. Tithi or lunar day is a period in which
>   the difference between the longitudes of Moon and Sun changes by exactly 12°.

Moon and Sun longitude positions are important to [determine the tithi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29231/3872) and when it will change.

> When Sun and Moon are at the same longitude, a new lunar month of 30 tithis starts.
>   As time progresses, Moon will go ahead of Sun. When Moon’s longitude is exactly
>   12° greater than Sun’s longitude, the first tithi or lunar day finishes and the second
>   tithi starts. When Moon’s longitude is exactly 24° greater than Sun’s longitude, the
>   second tithi finishes and the third tithi starts. When Moon’s longitude is exactly 36°
>   greater than Sun’s longitude, the third tithi finishes and the fourth tithi starts. And so
>   on. You can see that Sun-Moon longitude differential will be (12 x n)° after exactly n
>   tithis.